# DateFormatter's returns nil for specific date strings without time in Swift

Tags: ios, macos, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I really don't get what is happening with this code, I'm trying to convert a string to date. What I don't understand is that the conversion works for most of the dates, but doesn't work specially for only 2 dates.

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "es")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd 'de' MMMM"

dateFormatter.dateFromString("1 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("2 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("3 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("4 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("5 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("6 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("7 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("8 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("9 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("10 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("11 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("12 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("13 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("14 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("15 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("16 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("17 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("18 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("19 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("20 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("21 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("22 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("23 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("24 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("25 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("26 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("27 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("28 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("29 de octubre")
dateFormatter.dateFromString("30 de octubre")
```

I made this code to try out in Playground, but it reproduces some dates I'm getting in my production code. Take a look in the output that this code produces:

[image: Playground output]

As you can see in the image, it doesn't work for October 8 and 15. Works for all the others. I also tried August and September, and in those months all days work. I also tried to put the dates in Portuguese in pt-br locale, and also doesn't work for October 8 and 15. Is it explainable?

---

Update: @zneak code produces the following output for me:

[image: output]

In other words, stopped running October 8.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue with [this program](http://pastebin.com/x4nyXc1M).

Comment: You are trusting the debugger.  Never trust the debugger.  Assign the result to a variable and log it.

Comment: @zneak, your code produces the same error for me.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm not trusting the debugger, I used that to show the problem to you. I tried N ways to get that value.

Comment: It returns nil because that day is shorter and there is no 12:00 am considering the fact that day starts at 1:00 am because of the daylight savings time adjustment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to set your date formatter calendar property:

**Xcode 8.2.1 • Swift 3.0.2**

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "es")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd 'de' MMMM"
dateFormatter.date(from: "8 de octubre")   // "Oct 8, 2000, 1:00 AM"
```

Comment: For me, it worked without setting a calendar. Can you reproduce the problem without setting it?

Comment: Yes without setting a calendar it returns nil. It depends on your location

Comment: I tried [setting a date formatter to every calendar out there](http://pastebin.com/yWs6nCWA) and the only ones with which the formatter fails to parse dates are Chinese, Hebrew, Islamic, Islamic Civil, Persian and Indian; they fail across the board, not just for two dates per month. What is the identifier of your initial calendar?

Comment: Sorry sneak I don't understand your question but I use ISO8601 calendar. The problem is when you don't assign anyone. Gregorian calendar also works for me here

Comment: My `NSDateFormatter`s are initialized to the Gregorian calendar. That's why I'm asking what yours is initialized to: what's `dateFormatter.calendar.calendarIdentifier` for you?

Comment: @zneak dateFormatter.calendar.calendarIdentifier prints "gregorian" too.

Comment: And setting it to Gregorian again fixes the problem? That doesn't really look right. Consider filing a bug report if this really works.

Comment: @zneak Doing this makes the code work: dateFormatter.calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: dateFormatter.calendar.calendarIdentifier)