# Why get nil when try to using dateFormatter in iOS Swift 3?

Tags: swift, date, null, dateformatter

I try to convert date with String format to Date format like this:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"             
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2017-03-22")
```

But get nil value.

I set

```
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

but does not work...
Please help to fix this.

Comment: i got the output as `Optional(2017-03-21 18:30:00 +0000)`

Comment: this code works fine for me in playground

Comment: Can you give more context? where is it giving you nil? Where are you using this code?

Comment: You may need to set a calendar also http://stackoverflow.com/a/32408916/2303865

Comment: Show the full code of `viewForHeaderInSection` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you device calendar is set to something different from default Gregorian calendar which is supposed, adding this line will solve the problem:

```
dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
```

Also I noticed your date doesn't embed any timezone, if you have a fixed one, add this line too:

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
// Replace "UTC" with your desired timezone
```

the final code would be like this:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"             
dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2017-03-22")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

I added

```
dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
```

to script and works correctly.