# Swift language bug in DateFormatter?

Tags: swift, dateformatter

I was testing an app that has an UITextField where users enter a date, so I take the entered string and use a DateFormatter to generate a Date object.

The problem first occurred when I tried converting the string "10/15/2017" which returned a nil value. So I create a code to generate string from "01/01/2000" to "12/31/2020" and I realized that the problem is occurring in all years around October or November of each year.
I created a code to print all dates that return a nil value:

```
import UIKit
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")

for day in 1...30 { // Generate the days
    for month in 1...12 { // Generate the months
        for year in 2000...2020 {
            if month == 2, day > 28 { // Check if month is february
               continue
            }
            str = "\(String(format: "%02d", month))/\(String(format: "%02d", day))/\(String(format: "%02d", year))"
            let date = dateFormatter.date(from: str)          
            if date == nil {
                print("\(str)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried changing the `dateFormat`, or even the `locale` properties and I'm also getting nil for some entries.

`dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"`

This snippet of code prints the following:

```
11/02/2004
11/03/2002
11/05/2006
10/08/2000
10/14/2001
10/14/2007
10/15/2017
10/16/2005
10/16/2011
10/16/2016
10/17/2010
10/18/2009
10/18/2015
10/18/2020
10/19/2003
10/19/2008
10/19/2014
10/20/2013
10/20/2019
10/21/2012
10/21/2018
```

I'm using Xcode 8.3.3 and Swift 3. Is that a bug with Swift/Xcode or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. – But you should use a fixed `dateFormatter.dateFormat` (in your case: "MM/dd/yyyy") for *parsing* dates.

Comment: @MartinR I tried using `dateFormatter.dateFormat` with "MM/dd/yyyy" and also "dd/MM/yyyy" but I'm getting the same result.

Comment: What is your timezone?

Comment: My timezone is "America/Sao_Paulo" (UTC -3)

Comment: If you set timezone to `dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)`, you will not see this error.

Comment: You just need to set the dateFormatter calendar and you won't get any date == nil. `dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar.current`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32408916/2303865

Comment: @Rob All he needs is to set the Date Formatter calendar. No need to change the timeZone.

Comment: @LeoDabus - Cool. That's an interesting workaround. If `calendar` of the date formatter is "unspecified", "the logical calendar for the current user is used." I'd hate to write code dependent upon this undocumented "feature" that if you replace the logical calendar for the current user with the current calendar, that the behavior changes.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely the *Brazil-Fall-Syndrome*

The daylight saving changes in Brazil occur at midnight. In fall, when the clock is set forward, there is no 12:00 am / 0:00 so the date is `nil`.

Set the time zone to a country where daylight saving changes don't occur at midnight or set the hour to noon

Comment: All he needs is to set the Date Formatter calendar. No need to change the timeZone