# Date formatter not returning date from string in app works in playground though

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, dateformatter

I know these questions are asked all the time about date formatters, however the issue I have is really odd

I need to convert a simple string to date as follows

```
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
let dateOfBirthString = "10/20/2002"
let dob: Date? = dateFormatter.date(from: dateOfBirthString)
```

This works fine in a playground but always returns nil in the app (with those exact values (albeit properties rather than hard coded strings)

Any help would be appreciated, its driving me nuts

Comment: In the real app, are you 100% positive that the string really is `"10/20/2002"` with no whitespace or any other characters in the string?

Comment: I printed the string out to copy into the playground

Comment: That doesn't confirm whether the real string has any whitespace of any kind or not. Print the length of the string and make sure it is 10.

Comment: (lldb) po dateOfBirthString
▿ Optional<String>
  - some : "10/20/2002"

(lldb) po dateOfBirthString.count
10

Comment: Does seem to be something strange going on.  Just tried your code, and when I examine dob it comes up as nil, but when I examine it's description, I get the string represenation of the date:(lldb) e dob
(Date?) $R0 = nil
(lldb) e dob?.description
(String?) $R2 = "2002-10-19 23:00:00 +0000"
(lldb)

Comment: make sure to set your date formatter locale to `"en_US_POSIX"`. you should also set your date formatter's calendar https://stackoverflow.com/q/32408898/2303865

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
extension String {

func toDateTime() -> Date {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: self) else {
        preconditionFailure("Take a look to your format")
    }
    return date
}
}
```

try this extension

```
let dateOfBirthString = "10/20/2002"
let dob: Date? = dateOfBirthString.toDateTime()
```

use this extension like this and if you get any error then feel free to comment below

Comment: Hey thanks this solved it - just for reference  your second example creates a date formatter and string that's not needed. Also for the string extension I passed a parameter for the format type so I can utilise it for different date formats - thanks this was driving me nuts!

Comment: Okey I get it and happy to help you.

Comment: Thanks  - really appreciate the help