# Converting string to date returns nil yyyMMdd

Tags: swift, xcode, time-format

I am trying to convert my string to a date using a date formatter.

```
let timeSTR = "19740707"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from:timeSTR)
```

i am getting nil in the date object. any other timeSTR for example "1974070**6**" or "1974070**5**" or any other option will work ... 
we found that if we will add the following command

```
dateFormatter.timezone = Timezone(identifier:"UTC")
```

it's fix the problem ...

more similar date that will return nil are: 19560603 , 19440401, 19400601

any one have an idea what wrong with those values???

Adding Print screen from my Playground with value 19740707:
[image]

Adding Print screen from my Playground with value: "19740706"
[image]

Comment: try `dateformatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")` [more on this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1480/_index.html)

Comment: i try this in playground and getting date for all strs

Comment: Same here. Copied and pasted your code example and got a date.

Comment: Make sure to set your `dateFormatter.calendar` property to iso8601 and your formatter locale to `Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")` before setting its `dateFormat` property to "yyyyMMdd" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32408898/dateformatters-method-datefrom-string-returns-nil-for-specific-dates-in-spec/32408916?r=SearchResults&s=1|37.2693#32408916