# Date calculations are returning the wrong values

Tags: swift, date

I am trying to calculate the difference, in seconds, between two dates. The code below returns the incorrect values (compared to an existing perl script, by hand, and using the web). I followed many of the suggestions posted on this forum but the results returned are not correct. Please advise.

***Playground follows:***

```
import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"

let startMon = 05
let startMday = 26
let startYear = 2016
let startDateStr = "\(startYear)/\(startMon)/\(startMday)"
var difference = 0.0
let secondsPerYear = 31536000.00 //3.154e+7
let secondsPerDay = 86400.0

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
//let currentDate = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
let currentDate = Date()
let timeIntervalNow = currentDate.timeIntervalSince1970
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd"
let startDateFormatted = dateFormatter.date(from: startDateStr)
let startDateInterval = startDateFormatted?.timeIntervalSince1970
difference = timeIntervalNow - startDateInterval!
print("difference == \(difference)")
let years = difference/secondsPerYear
print("Years == \(years)")
//let difference = startDateFormatted?.timeIntervalSince(currentDate)
difference = currentDate.timeIntervalSince(startDateFormatted!)
print("difference == \(difference)")
let years_1 = difference/secondsPerYear
print("Years == \(years_1)")

let days = difference/secondsPerDay
print("days == \(days)")
/*
difference == 126336349.94199085
Years == 4.006099376648619
difference == 126336349.94199097
Years == 4.006099376648623
days == 1462.234392008496

Calculated On the web:

 3 years, 8 months, 2 days including the end date.
 115,948,800 seconds
 1,341 days
 */
```

Comment: For a starter: The date format for  the month is "MM", not "mm". Documented at https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns.

Comment: Indeed. A simple `print(startDateFormatted)` would have revealed `2016-01-25 22:00:00 +0000`

Comment: @Brad: Debugging seems to be a dying art...

Comment: Not for this old PDP 11 macro hacker...

Answer (score 2):

The major mistake is the date format: `mm` is minutes, `MM` is months.

Nevertheless `Calendar` can calculate date differences much more reliable than horrible *86400 math*

```
let startMon = 05
let startMday = 26
let startYear = 2016
let startDateStr = "\(startYear)/\(startMon)/\(startMday)"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let currentDate = Date()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier : "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
let startDateFormatted = dateFormatter.date(from: startDateStr)

let difference = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: startDateFormatted!, to: Date())
print(difference)
```

Or with `DateComponents`

```
let startMon = 05
let startMday = 26
let startYear = 2016
let startComponents = DateComponents(year: startYear, month: startMon, day: startMday)
let nowComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Date())

let difference = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: startComponents, to: nowComponents)
print(difference)
```

Comment: Thanks for the corrections and tips. Sounds like I need to veer away from the 86400 math.

Comment: @vadian you forgot to set DateFormatter's locale to `"en_US_POSIX"` https://stackoverflow.com/a/40702569/2303865 and its calendar to `.gregorian` when parsing a fixed date format. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32408916/2303865

Comment: @vadian, how do I print out the difference in seconds between the two dates?

Comment: Rather than `[.year, .month, .day]` use `[.second]`