# Why does DateFormatter.date(from:) return nil instead of Date object?

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I have created the following, simple Swift function to convert a String into a `Date` object. However, the `dateFormatter` always returns `nil`, even on valid inputs like `2020-02-27`

```
func date(fromString str: String?) -> Date? {
    if let dateStr = str {
        if dateStr.count == 0 {
            return nil
        }

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

        let result = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr)         // --> nil
        //let result = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020-02-27")  // --> nil as well

        return result
    }
```

This is (more or less) a ported version some Objectiv-C code where everything works fine.

How to fix this?

**UPDATE:**

As mentioned in the comments the problem does NOT show when I execute the code in Swift Playground. **It seems that this is some wired problem with Xcode and the simulator. I will re-check this!**

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue: `print(date(fromString: "2020-02-27")) // Optional(2020-02-26 23:00:00 +0000)`

Comment: Are you sure your input, `str`, isn't nil? Off-topic but I would recommend using `guard` at the beginning, `guard let dateStr = str, !str.isEmpty else {return nil}` to increase readability

Comment: Not related, but `guard let dateStr = str, dateStr.isEmpty == false else { return nil }` might be clearer.

Comment: First check your input, is it the correct string or not?. after that check your input, is it actually "yyyy-MM-dd" format or not?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this as well. Putting this code into a Swift Playground successfully returns `Optional(2020-02-27 05:00:00 +0000)`.

Comment: Also unrelated to your question, but creating a `DateFormatter` is quite expensive, so you shouldn't do that inside a function. Store it as a property of your class instead.

Comment: Note that you should always set timezone as well to solve problems with DST changes, e.g. `TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT()`.

Comment: If the question was correctly answered, why do you not accept that answer?

Comment: @Sulthan DateFormatter's default timezone it is already the current one. `TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT)` is pointless. What you need is to set its calendar.

Comment: @LeoDabus Not at all. The thing is that you want to avoid a time zone with DST changes. If you don't do that then your parsing starts falling on specific days. Setting the time zone is also mentioned in the famous Technical Note about parsing internet dates. When you are parsing a date without actual time information, the problem gets even more interesting.

Comment: Check the duplicate question

Answer (score 0):

Set the calendar too:

```
dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
```

Comment: Thank! I do not understand why, but this solved the problem...

Comment: @AndreiHerford that's because you haven't provided the time components on your string. Not every day starts at 12am. Depending on your location and day it might be the start of daylight savings time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32408898/dateformatters-method-datefrom-string-returns-nil-for-specific-dates-in-spec