# Dates are returning a nil when trying to compare oldest Swift

Tags: swift, sorting, datetime

Here's my date compare code: I am currently getting nil values for date1 and date2. the struct model with the actual dates,  the strings are optional, since the service could return nil. currently, in my test example, the first and second dates have string values, but in the func() date1 and date2 are nil.

```
    // these date strings are in a struct, placed here for clarity
    var date1: String?
    var date2: String?
    
    // from the response
    // date1 = "10/20/2018"
    // date2 = "10/20/2019"
    
        func getOldestDate(_ firstDate: String, secondDate: String, formatter: String) -> String {
             
             let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
             dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
             
             let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
             dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = dateFormat
             
             let date1: Date? = dateFormatterGet.date(from: firstDate)
             let date2: Date? = dateFormatterGet.date(from: secondDate)
             
             if firstDate.compare(secondDate) == .orderedAscending {
                 return dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date1!);
             } else {
                 return dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date2!);
             }
         }

// This func is just to test the compare method

    func tryThis() {
        if let dateA = "10/20/2018" as? String , let dateB = "10/20/2019" as? String {
            print("\(getOldestDate(dateA, secondDate: dateB, formatter: dateFormat))")
        }
    }
```

I don't really care about tryThis() as I'm just forcing some string values to date1, date2. But is that the reason they are nil in my func and when run against a JSON response, the func should work?

Comment: Sorry but I'm confused about what the question is.

Comment: The `dateFormat` doesn't match at all the string date: Does `"10/20/2018"` looks like `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"` to you? Try maybe `"MM/dd/yyyy"` instead...

Comment: @matt, sorry, in the getOldestDate func, date1 and date2 are nil .Okay, I was wondering if my formatter was wrong. @ Larme, Thanks! the JSON string is in the format in the function, so I forgot to update my code to test outside of the project.   Live and learn!

Comment: But you see, then the title of your question should not be "Get oldest of two Date() objects in Swift". That's totally irrelevant. It should be something more like "Why are my dates nil?"

Comment: @matt,  Yes I understand now..I do apologize for the bad wording in my question. I will do better next time.

Comment: @jayskev you can [edit] your question and fix it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here's how you can get the older date. I updated your code.

```swift
func getOldestDate(firstDate: String, secondDate: String, dateFormat: String ) -> String? {
    
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = .autoupdatingCurrent
    dateFormatter.locale = .autoupdatingCurrent
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
    
    guard let date1 = dateFormatter.date(from: firstDate) else { return nil}
    guard let date2 = dateFormatter.date(from: secondDate) else { return nil}
    
    if firstDate > secondDate {
        return dateFormatter.string(from: date2)
    } else {
        return dateFormatter.string(from: date1)
    }
}

// call method
getOldestDate(firstDate: "10/20/2018", secondDate: "10/20/2017", dateFormat: "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: Thanks @Aafaq!!

Comment: You are welcome, if you think answer correct, mark as correct.

Comment: I must be too new, its not letting me upvote?

Comment: You need to earn few more reputation.

Comment: @jayskev Don’t use this approach. It is creating a new date when parsing fails. Btw what is the expected result if one date is nil?

Comment: You can get rid of NilCoalescing, however, it will get crashed when found nothing.

Comment: Updated the approach for better handling.

Comment: Ah ! Yes if Either of the dates are nil from the service, then there should be no string value for the label. For now it simply would default to an empty string.

Comment: There still some issues with this code. There is no time on those date strings. If you receive a daylight savings transition date (where might have no midnight) the parsing will fail. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32408916/2303865

Comment: Also `mm ` is for minutes not month !!!

Comment: Should study a bit more before posting some answers on a public forum. And "month" and days are swaped in your date format. That was probably to "fix" the parsing failing.

Comment: Okay @LeoDabus thanks! I have corrrected.

Comment: @Aafaq Did you read all my comments? Did you check the link I posted above? Again you need to set the date formatter calendar's property. Also when parsing a fixed date format you should use "en_US_POSIX"

Comment: You should take some time and read the documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1480/_index.html

Comment: **if you're working with fixed-format dates, you should first set the locale of the date formatter to something appropriate for your fixed format. In most cases the best locale to choose is "en_US_POSIX", a locale that's specifically designed to yield US English results regardless of both user and system preferences. "en_US_POSIX" is also invariant in time (if the US, at some point in the future, changes the way it formats dates, "en_US" will change to reflect the new behaviour, but "en_US_POSIX" will not), and between machines ("en_US_POSIX" works the same on iOS as it does on OS X,**

Comment: **and as it it does on other platforms).

Once you've set "en_US_POSIX" as the locale of the date formatter, you can then set the date format string and the date formatter will behave consistently for all users.**