# DateFormatter fails to parse specific date

Tags: swift

Im having a weird issue related to parsing `String` to `Date` in swift.
This is the code I put in the Playground:

[image: screenshot from Playgroud.swift]

Im wondering why DateFormatter fails to parse only the 28 May 1972 date?
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure there are no invisible chars in the "28" string, and all "-" chars are actually "minus" characters?

Comment: I think there is a typo here.

Comment: @Gereon Yes, I'm sure, I just wrote by keyboard

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32408916/2303865

Comment: Just make sure to set your date formatter’s locale and calendar

Comment: @LeoDabus Yep, the issue was that, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your name suggests that you are living in Italy.

In [Italy daylight saving time changed on May 28, 1972 at 00:00](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/italy?year=1972).

This hour haven't existed because the clocks were turned forward to 01:00.

Comment: Op is not specifying any time. The issue is the lack of information when OP does NOT set the date formatter’s calendar and locale. Once this is set date formatter’s will NOT return nil

Comment: @LeoDabus The question is *why DateFormatter fails to parse only the 28 May 1972 date*?

Comment: You totally right, I'm in Italy! And I was missing the timezone. Thanks