26 March of 1995 could not be mapped into date using Europe/Sofia timezone
DateFomatter could not init the date from "1995-03-26" string when using "Europe/Sofia" timezone. I've also tried to use different timezones and everything works correctly, but not for this specific timezone. What is the reason for this strange behaviour?
import Foundation

let serverLocalDateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-d"
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 60 * 60 * 2)
    
    return formatter
}()

let serverLocalDateFormatter2: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-d"
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Sofia")
    
    return formatter
}()

let testCase1 = "1995-03-26"
let testCase2 = "1995-03-27"
let testCase3 = "1995-03-25"

serverLocalDateFormatter.date(from: testCase1)
serverLocalDateFormatter2.date(from: testCase1)
serverLocalDateFormatter.date(from: testCase2)
serverLocalDateFormatter.date(from: testCase3)

I've created date formatter and used `date(from: String) method to get the date from the string that is returned from the backend, but only one specific date could not be parsed.

26 March 1995 was the start of Daylight Saving Time in Bulgaria. Bulgaria changes its clocks at midnight, so if you're just using the date portion, the effective time is midnight, and the formatter may not be able to handle the ambiguity.

Why the downvotes? This seems like a legitimate question, and the OP provided code to reproduce the case they are talking about. I up-voted it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32408916/2303865

IMO the right thing to do when you need a time insensitive date is to set the formatters defaultDate to noon 12:00pm or just append the time 12:00pm to your  Date string before parsing it.

The formatter assumes the string represents a date with the time 00:00:00, but the datetime 1995-03-26T00:00:00 doesn't exist in Bulgaria's timezone, because this is when a Bulgaria transitions into daylight saving time in 1995, "skipping" a whole hour starting from 00:00:00.
You can set isLenient to true to have it return the start of the day of 1995-03-26, which is at 1am.
formatter.isLenient = true

Having the formatter be lenient also allows for other "malformed" dates like "1995-03-32" to be successfully parsed, but since this seems to be parsing dates that come from a server, this shouldn't matter too much.

No need to set lenient to true. You can fix it by setting the DateFormatter’s calendar property
